# .NET Core Dependency Injection resolve question

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

In my startup of my WebApi project I've got the next code:

```
services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<OpdrachtgeverToevoegenCommand>, OpdrachtgeverCommandHandler>();
services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<OpdrachtgeverVerwijderenCommand>, OpdrachtgeverCommandHandler>();
services.AddScoped<ICommandHandler<OpdrachtgeverWijzigenCommand>, OpdrachtgeverCommandHandler>();
```

In my project I've got implementations of these interfaces.

Now I'm trying to find the correct implementation of this handler by using the command:

Here's the code that isn't completed yet:

```
public static ICommandHandler<ICommand> GetHandler(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ICommand command)
{
    if (serviceProvider == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));
    if (command == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));

    var handler = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(command.GetType());
    return serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(command.GetType()) as ICommandHandler<ICommand>;
}
```

I know that the `command.GetType()` returns the correct command, but how do I find the `ICommandHandler<command.GetType()>` implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could dynamically make the type that you are looking up using `MakeGenericType`:

```
   var handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(command.GetType());
   return (ICommandHandler<ICommand>) serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(handlerType);
```

However, this will give you problems since I'm assuming that `ICommandHandler<>` is not covariant. You will not be able to cast it to `ICommandHandler<ICommand>`.

It's better to pass the type of command to the method as a generic argument.

```
public static ICommandHandler<TCommand> GetHandler<TCommand>(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, TCommand command)
{
    return serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>();
}
```

Comment: Thank u Tim. The second solution was the one that I already had, but because I'm using now baseclasses and a basecontroller, it doesn't work. The first one worked for now, and i'm thinking about some changes. Thanks!